# Synchronize language switcher with language from user profile

Tags: drupal-6

I have a multilanguage site in drupal 6. I use ip 2 locale module. In a dropdown menu it's a language switcher. When an user switches a language I want to change the language from its profile (language settings) with selected language from menu. How to synchronize language from menu with language from user profile?